# Java Trie Matching using Iterator

Tags: java, tree, trie

I have an assignment which involves creating a Trie of company names (read from a file) and then reading a news article input and counting the number of times a company name from the Trie occurs in the article.

I have coded a pretty standard Trie structure, however for the assignment it made more sense to have the TrieNodes hold the full word rather than just each character.

To make things more complicated, each company name from the file has one "primary name" and can have multiple "secondary names". For example: Microsoft Corporation, Microsoft, Xbox - where the first name is always the primary.

The assignment requires that I count all matches in the article for any of the company names, but only return the company's primary name when printing the results. Because of this, my TrieNode has the String primeName datafield, along with the standard isEnd bool. However, in my case, isEnd represents whether or not the specified node and its parent(s) form a full company name.

For example, with the article input "Microsoft Corporation just released a new Xbox console." I would need to return something along the lines of "Microsoft:2" because both Microsoft Corporation and Xbox share the same primary company name which is Microsoft.

I am using an iterator in the getHits() method but when I do find a hit, I need to look at the next word in the array to make sure it is not a continuation before I decide whether to stop or continue. The problem is that calling iter.next() doesn't just "peek" the next value but it moves forward, essentially causing me to skip words.

For example, if you look at the below code and my example, after "Best" gets a hit, it should see that "Buy" is a child and the next time it loops get a match on "Buy", but since I already call iter.next() to look at "Buy" within the While loop, the next iteration entirely skips "Buy". Is there some way I can simply peek at the next iter value within the While loop without actually moving to it? Also, any improvements to this code are greatly appreciated! I am sure there are many places where I sloppily implemented something.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.*;

public class BuildTrie {


    // Class Methods
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Trie Companies = new Trie();

        String filename = "companies.dat";
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Split line by tab character
                String[] aliases = line.replaceAll("\\p{P}", "").split("\t");
                // Loop over each "alias" of specific company
                for (int n = 0; n < aliases.length; n++) {
                    String[] name = aliases[n].split(" ");
                    // Insert each alias into Trie with index 0 as primary
                    Companies.insert(name, aliases[0]);
                }

            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.format("Exception occurred trying to read '%s'.", filename);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /*System.out.println("Article Input: ");
        try (BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                if (".".equals(line)) break;
                String[] items = line.trim().replaceAll("\\p{P}", "").split("\\s+");
                for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    Companies.words.add(items[i]);
                    //System.out.println(items[i]);
                }
            }
        }*/

        Companies.articleAdd("The");
        Companies.articleAdd("company");
        Companies.articleAdd("Best");
        Companies.articleAdd("Buy");
        Companies.articleAdd("sell");
        Companies.articleAdd("Xbox");

        Companies.getHits();

    }

}

// Trie Node, which stores a character and the children in a HashMap
class TrieNode {
    // Data Fields
    private String word;
    HashMap<String,TrieNode> children;
    boolean bIsEnd;
    private String primary = "";

    // Constructors
    public TrieNode() {
        children = new HashMap<>();
        bIsEnd = false;
    }
    public TrieNode(String st, String prime)  {
        word = st;
        children = new HashMap<>();
        bIsEnd = false;
        primary = prime;
    }

    // Trie Node Methods
    public HashMap<String,TrieNode> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return word;
    }
    public void setIsEnd(boolean val) {
        bIsEnd = val;
    }
    public boolean isEnd() {
        return bIsEnd;
    }
    public String getPrime() {
        return primary;
    }
}

class Trie {
    private ArrayList<String> article = new ArrayList<String>();
    private HashMap<String,Integer> hits = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

    // Constructor
    public Trie() {
        root = new TrieNode();
    }

    // Insert article text
    public void articleAdd(String word) {
        article.add(word);
    }

    // Method to insert a new company name to Trie
    public void insert(String[] names, String prime)  {

        // Find length of the given name
        int length = names.length;
        //TrieNode currNode = root;

        HashMap<String,TrieNode> children = root.children;

        // Traverse through all words of given name
        for( int i=0; i<length; i++)
        {
            String name = names[i];
            System.out.println("Iter: " + name);
            TrieNode t;
            // If there is already a child for current word of given name
            if( children.containsKey(name))
                t = children.get(name);
            else   // Else create a child
            {
                System.out.println("Inserting node " + name + " prime is " + prime);
                t = new TrieNode(name, prime);
                children.put( name, t );
            }
            children = t.getChildren();

            int j = names.length-1;
            if(i==j){
                t.setIsEnd(true);
                System.out.println("WordEnd");
            }
        }
    }

    public void getHits() {
        // String[] articleArr = article.toArray(new String[0]);
        // Initialize reference to traverse through Trie
        // TrieNode crawl = root;
        // int level, prevMatch = 0;
        Iterator<String> iter = article.iterator();
        TrieNode currNode = root;

        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            String word = iter.next();
            System.out.println("Iter: " + word);
            // HashMap of current node's children
            HashMap<String,TrieNode> child = currNode.getChildren();
            // If hit in currNode's children
            if (child.containsKey(word)) {
                System.out.println("Node exists: " + word);
                // Update currNode to be node that matched
                currNode = child.get(word);
                System.out.println(currNode.isEnd());
                String next = "";
                // If currNode is leaf and next node has no match in children, were done
                if (iter.hasNext()) {next = iter.next();}
                if (currNode.isEnd() && !child.containsKey(next)) {
                        System.out.println("Matched word: " + word);
                        System.out.println("Primary: " + currNode.getPrime());
                        currNode = root;
                    } else {
                    // Else next node is continuation

                }

            } else {
             // Else ignore next word and reset

                currNode = root;
            }
        }
    }
    private TrieNode root;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of using while and iter.next() you can use for loop as below

> for (Map.Entry entry : article.entrySet()) {
>       String word = entry.getKey();
>
> }

So you are not really moving to the next items of your hashmap.

If this is not your point, please clarify us.

Thanks,
Nghia

Comment: Thanks Nghia, I actually tried that right after posting and it seems to have worked as expected (with some minor tweaks to my logic).

Answer (score 0):

I opted to use a for-loop style instead of While loop for this, as well as tweaked some logic to get it working. For those interested, the new code is below, as well as an example of the "companies.dat" file (what is populated to the Trie). The stdin is any text excerpt which ends with a "." on new line.

Companies.dat:

```
Microsoft Corporation   Microsoft   Xbox
Apple Computer  Apple   Mac
Best Buy
Dell
```

TrieBuilder:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.*;

public class BuildTrie {

    // Class Methods
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Trie Companies = new Trie();

        String filename = "companies.dat";
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Split line by tab character
                String[] aliases = line.replaceAll("\\p{P}", "").split("\t");
                // Loop over each "alias" of specific company
                for (int n = 0; n < aliases.length; n++) {
                    String[] name = aliases[n].split(" ");
                    // Insert each alias into Trie with index 0 as primary
                    Companies.insert(name, aliases[0]);
                }

            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.format("Exception occurred trying to read '%s'.", filename);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Article Input: ");
        try (BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                if (".".equals(line)) break;
                String[] items = line.trim().replaceAll("\\p{P}", "").split("\\s+");
                for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    Companies.articleAdd(items[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        Companies.getHits();

    }

}

// Trie Node, which stores a character and the children in a HashMap
class TrieNode {
    // Data Fields
    private String word;
    HashMap<String,TrieNode> children;
    boolean bIsEnd;
    private String primary = "";

    // Constructors
    public TrieNode() {
        children = new HashMap<>();
        bIsEnd = false;
    }
    public TrieNode(String st, String prime)  {
        word = st;
        children = new HashMap<>();
        bIsEnd = false;
        primary = prime;
    }

    // Trie Node Methods
    public HashMap<String,TrieNode> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return word;
    }
    public void setIsEnd(boolean val) {
        bIsEnd = val;
    }
    public boolean isEnd() {
        return bIsEnd;
    }
    public String getPrime() {
        return primary;
    }
}

class Trie {
    private ArrayList<String> article = new ArrayList<String>();
    private HashMap<String,Integer> hits = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

    // Constructor
    public Trie() {
        root = new TrieNode();
    }

    // Insert article text
    public void articleAdd(String word) {
        article.add(word);
    }

    // Method to insert a new company name to Trie
    public void insert(String[] names, String prime)  {

        // Find length of the given name
        int length = names.length;

        HashMap<String,TrieNode> children = root.children;

        // Traverse through all words of given name
        for( int i=0; i<length; i++)
        {
            String name = names[i];
            TrieNode t;
            // If there is already a child for current word of given name
            if( children.containsKey(name))
                t = children.get(name);
            else   // Else create a child
            {
                t = new TrieNode(name, prime);
                children.put( name, t );
            }
            children = t.getChildren();

            int j = names.length-1;
            if(i==j){
                t.setIsEnd(true);
            }
        }
    }

    public void getHits() {
        // Initialize reference to traverse through Trie
        TrieNode currNode = root;

        for (int i=0; i < article.size(); i++) {
            String word = article.get(i);
            System.out.println("Searching: " + word);
            // HashMap of current node's children
            HashMap<String, TrieNode> child = currNode.getChildren();
            // If hit in currNode's children
            if (child.containsKey(word)) {
                System.out.println("Node exists: " + word);
                // Update currNode to be node that matched
                currNode = child.get(word);
                child = currNode.getChildren();
                System.out.println("isEnd?: " + currNode.isEnd());
                String next = "";
                if (i+1 < article.size()) {
                    next = article.get(i+1);
                }
                // If currNode is leaf and next node has no match in children, were done
                if (currNode.isEnd() && !child.containsKey(next)) {
                    System.out.println("Primary of match: " + currNode.getPrime());
                    currNode = root;
                }
            } else {
                // Else ignore next word and reset
                System.out.println("No match.");
                currNode = root;
            }
        }
    }
    private TrieNode root;
}
```